# How to design this one-to-many schema in a NoSQL database?

Tags: mongodb

I just start learning MongoDB this week. Prior to it, I am only familiar with SQL, so it takes some times for me to convert my logic.

I have a simple question here about a one-to-many relationship.

Assume that I have a book for rental, and I want to record the rental history. Which schema I should use?

Plan A: Create a document, use BookId as reference, and hold all the rental history.

Plan B: Create multiple documents and use BookId as reference. Every time when the book is rented out, I will create a document for it.

Which plan is better? I guess Plan B is better but I am just not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/ has good advice on how to structure your collections.

Either of your schemes could work BUT if there are a very large number of rentals per book you MUST use plan B because a document has a maximum size.

You can also mix plan A and B, for example, using plan B but also storing a limited array of recent rentals with the book so that you can satisfy the initial query with one trip to the database but if the user then scrolls down to see more you start fetching the rental records.

You can often start by thinking of it like you would in SQL but then adding some denormalization when you need to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I read the link you provided before I post this question, and that is the reason I asked here. Although MongoDb is not a relational database, it works just like SQL. :)

Comment: @user361022-not sure what you mean, but MongoDb doesn't behave, query, or model like any traditional RDBMS, so I'm not sure what you meant.